# If we pick a sequence of numbers $(a_k)$ at random, what is the expected radius of convergence of $\sum_k a_k x^k$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, power-series, generating-functions, expected-value

Suppose we pick a sequence of positive integers independently and identically distributed from $\mathbb{N}^+$: call it $(a_k)=(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$. If we consider the corresponding generating function $f(x) = \sum_k a_k x^k$, what can we say about the radius of convergence $R$ of $f$? The Cauchy-Hadamard theorem says $R^{-1}= \limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}$, but I'm wondering if we can say any more from a probabilistic standpoint.

Here are my thoughts (mostly low-hanging fruit) on the problem if the $a_k$ are positive integers.

- If $(a_k)$ is bounded, we have $R=1$; this follows immediately by comparison to the geometric series. I don't think "most" positive integer sequences are bounded; in fact, I suspect they are of measure zero in the set of all such sequences.
- If $a_k = O(k^r)$ for any real $r$, $R=1$ as well. Likewise, if $a_k = O(M^k)$, $R=M^{-1}$; by the integer stipulation, we must have $M\geq 1$.
- If the $a_k$ are positive integers, I don't think we can do better than $R=1$.

I thought about how to generalize the problem if we allow the $a_k$ to be real numbers; I haven't thought about the complex case. Here are my thoughts, again somewhat rudimentary.

- If the $a_k$ are eventually zero, obviously $R=\infty$.
- We can now have $a_k = O(M^k)$ for any $M>0$ (for instance, the Maclaurin series for tangent gives $R=\pi/2$)
- Analyzing convergence at the boundary is probably a lost cause

Please feel free to ask for clarification or to change the tags if you think they could be improved.

Update: instead of, "pick a sequence of positive integers independently and identically distributed from $\mathbb{N}^+$," perhaps I should specify a distribution. After looking at several common models, I think a Boltzmann or logarithmic distribution might be best, but I'm not sure. I realize this is an important aspect of the problem and I'm sorry I don't have a better idea of what to ask.

Comment: There is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{N}$. For any distribution where the question makes sense, though, I'm pretty sure you can make a case that the radius of convergence is 1 with probability 1. (There may be some distributions where the radius of convergence is 0 with probability 1, but it's very possible that that case can't exist; I haven't looked very closely. Anything else is, I'm reasonably sure, impossible.)

Comment: Just to expand on @StevenStadnicki's first sentence: what do you think is the probability of choosing $42$ from a uniform distribution on $\Bbb N$?

Comment: To be frank, I don't know a lot about probability and was just trying to say, "choose a sequence of numbers at random." If there's a more accurate way to say that, I'm happy to update the question.

Comment: I'm confused why we are assuming OP means uniform on $\mathbb{N}^+$ when the word is never used in their post?

Comment: @Integrand: fair enough.  The trouble is, the phrase "at random" does make a lot of sense, but it doesn't quite make sense for the natural numbers.  In particular, "at random" typically means that every sequence has the same probability of occurring.  But that breaks the probability axioms, because the infinite sum of any finite number (other than 0) is infinite.  So you sort of have to tell us how the sequences are chosen, or put some other constraint on things.

Comment: @AlexR. Apologies; I wasn't trying to assume; I was just noting since OP didn't say anything one way or the other. As I said in the second half of my comment, I'm reasonably sure the result is largely independent of whatever distribution is chosen, that there are only two possibilities and one I'm not even sure of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mu:=E[a_0]$. Define $Y_i:=a_ix^i$, so that $\mu_i:=E[Y_i]=\mu x^i$ and $\mbox{Var}(Y_i)=x^{2i}\mbox{Var}(a_0)$. The [Kolmogorov 2-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem) states that $\sum_i Y_i$ converges almost surely (is finite, in fact) if $\sum_i\mu_i$ and $\sum_i \mbox{Var}(Y_i)$ both converge.

This reduces to $\sum_{i\geq 0}x^i$ converging (so $R=1$) and $\sum_i x^{2i}$ converging (also $R=1$)

There's a possibility that $R>1$ is possible, but for that you'd need the [3-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) and likely more subtle info on the nature of the distribution of $X_i$. You'd also need the 3-series theorem if the sum of expected values or variances diverges to establish convergence.

Comment: What about the cases where the process doesn't have finite expectation? For instance, one might choose an integer $i$ with probability proportional to $i^{-2}$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Right, that's what I mean by referring to the 3-series theorem, which I believe will help resolve those cases. I've made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a probability distribution $\mathbb{P}$ on the positive integers $\mathbb{N}$, and let $p_n = \mathbb{P}(n)$. For $i \geq 0$, let $A_i$ be independent random variables, positive-integer-valued, with the distribution $\mathbb{P}$, so that $\mathbb{P}(A_i = n) = p_n$. Then the random power series

$$ \sum_{k \geq 0} A_k x^k$$

has a random radius of convergence $R$, which is itself the inverse of the random variable $X$ defined by:

$$X = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n^{1/n}.$$

If $p_0 = 1$ then this power series is boring; it is identically zero. So let's assume $p_0 < 1$. Under this assumption, we find the following about the radius of convergence:

**Claim:** Suppose $p_0 < 1$. With probability 1, $X \geq 1$, so $R = X^{-1} \leq 1$.

*Proof:* $X < 1$ only if $A_n = 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, but since $p_0 < 1$, for any fixed $N \geq 0$,

$$\mathbb{P}(\forall n \geq N, A_n = 0) \leq \mathbb{P}(A_N = A_{N+1} = ... = A_{N+k} = 0) = (1-p_0)^{k+1},$$

and since $k$ was arbitrary, this demonstrates $\mathbb{P}(\forall n \geq N, A_n = 0) = 0$.

You could achieve any desired radius of convergence $< 1$ almost surely by letting $\mathbb{P}$ be supported on a sufficiently sparse set - for example, the set of powers of $2$, or the set of factorials.

Comment: Actually, I realize OP's question meant $A_n \geq 1$ for all $n$, so $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n^{1/n} \geq 1$ completely trivially.